# Sorting by maximum array field, ascending or descending

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my Meteor app, I have a collection of documents with an array of subdocuments that look like this:

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5xF9iDTj3reLDKNHh",
    "name" : "Lorem ipsum",
    "revisions" : [ 
        {
            "number" : 0,
            "comment" : "Dolor sit amet",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T01:22:45.588Z")
        }
    ],
    "number" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "qTF8kEphNoB3eTNRA",
    "name" : "Consecitur quinam",
    "revisions" : [ 
        {
             "comment" : "Hoste ad poderiquem",
             "number" : 1,
             "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T23:25:46.033Z")
        }, 
        {
            "number" : 0,
            "comment" : "Fagor questibilus",
            "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T01:22:45.588Z")
        }
    ],
    "number" : 2
}
```

What I want to do is query this collection and sort the result set by the **maximum date** in the `created` field of the `revisions` array. Something I haven't been able to pull off yet. Some constraints I have are:

- Just sorting by `revisions.created` doesn't cut it, because the date used from the collection depends on the sort direction. I have to use the **maximum date** in the set regardless of sort order.
- I cannot rely on post-query manipulation of an unsorted result set, so, this must be done by a proper query or aggregation by the database.
- There's no guarantee that the `revisions` array will be pre-sorted.
- There may be extra fields in some documents and those have to come along, so careful with `$project`.
- Meteor is still using MongoDB 2.6, newer API features are no good :(

Comment: On the shell, that would be `db.coll.find(yourQuery).sort({"revisions.created":-1})`. I have not the slightest clue about meteor, so you need to translate it yourself.

Comment: @Markus That works when I sort descending but not ascending. Then it uses the minimum in the set.

Comment: Well, Thais exactly what your question stated. You might want to reword it and describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @Markus that's right. Editing now.

Comment: I still don't get it. You don't sort by a certain date. You sort by date, either ascending or descending. Is it possible that you want to query all records which share the maximum date?

Comment: I want to find the highest date in the `revisions` array, and use that to sort the top-level documents. Each document has multiple dates, and I need the highest in each document for sorting at the top level, ascending or descending.

Answer (score 4):

The basic problem with what you are asking here comes down to the fact that the data in question is within an "array", and therefore there are some basic assumptions made by MongoDB as to how this gets handled.

If you applied a sort in "descending order", then MongoDB will do exactly what you ask and sort the documents by the "largest" value of the specified field within the array:

```js
.sort({ "revisions.created": -1 ))
```

But if instead you sort in "ascending" order then of course the reverse is true and the "smallest" value is considered.

```js
.sort({ "revisions.created": 1 })
```

So the only way of doing this means working out which is the maximum date from the data in the array, and then sorting on that result. This basically means applying `.aggregate()`, which for meteor is a server side operation, being unfortunately something like this:

```js
Collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$revisions" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "revisions": { "$push": "$revisions" },
        "number": { "$first": "$number" }
        "maxDate": { "$max": "$revisions.created" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "maxDate": 1 }
])
```

Or at best with MongoDB 3.2, where [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) can be applied directly to an array expression:

```js
Collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "revisions": 1,
        "number": 1,
        "maxDate": {
            "$max": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$revisions",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": "$$el.created"
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "maxDate": 1 } }
])
```

But really both are not that great, even if the MongoDB 3.2 approach has way less overhead than what is available to prior versions, it's still not as good as you can get in terms of performance due to the need to pass through the data and work out the value to sort on.

So for **best** performance, "always" keep such data you are going to need "outside" of the array. For this there is the [`$max` "update"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) operator, which will only replace a value within the document "if" the provided value is "greater than" the existing value already there. i.e:

```js
Collection.update(
    { "_id": "qTF8kEphNoB3eTNRA" },
    { 
        "$push": {
            "revisions": { "created": new Date("2016-02-01") }            
        },
        "$max": { "maxDate": new Date("2016-02-01") }
    }
)
```

This means that the value you want will "always" be already present within the document with the expected value, so it is just now a simple matter of sorting on that field:

```js
.sort({ "maxDate": 1 })
```

So for my money, I would go though the existing data with either of the `.aggregate()` statements available, and use those results to update each doccument to contain a "maxDate" field. Then change the coding of all additions and revisions of array data to apply that [`$max` "update"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) on every change.

Having a solid field rather than a calculation always makes much more sense if you are using it often enough. And the maintenance is quite simple.

---

In any case, considering the above applied example date, which is "less than" the other maximum dates present would return for me in all forms:

```js
{
        "_id" : "5xF9iDTj3reLDKNHh",
        "name" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "revisions" : [
                {
                        "number" : 0,
                        "comment" : "Dolor sit amet",
                        "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T01:22:45.588Z")
                }
        ],
        "number" : 1,
        "maxDate" : ISODate("2016-02-11T01:22:45.588Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "qTF8kEphNoB3eTNRA",
        "name" : "Consecitur quinam",
        "revisions" : [
                {
                        "comment" : "Hoste ad poderiquem",
                        "number" : 1,
                        "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T23:25:46.033Z")
                },
                {
                        "number" : 0,
                        "comment" : "Fagor questibilus",
                        "created" : ISODate("2016-02-11T01:22:45.588Z")
                },
                {
                        "created" : ISODate("2016-02-01T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "number" : 2,
        "maxDate" : ISODate("2016-02-11T23:25:46.033Z")
}
```

Which correctly places the first document at the top of the sort order with consideration to the "maxDate".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One problem I have is that every time there's a new revision added, one has to remember to update the `maxDate` field as well, otherwise it will break. If there's a way to automate it, that would be acceptable as well.

Comment: @edgerunner That's basically what I am saying here. So whether it's a `$push` or a `$set` on an existing element ( and really only if "created" actually changed there ) then you would also apply the `$max`. to the `maxDate` value for the document. Yes, it's more work. You could add in some code to just add that "key" to any update object if you needed to, but to be careful to have no other operation on the same `maxDate` path ( not that you should need to for this purpose ). The trade off here is doing that to each update, or alternately working with aggregate on every request.