# Sorting on multiple fields with equal priority

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
OneCollection.find({}, {sort: {time1: -1, time2: -1}});
```

This one, `time1` is prior to `time2`.

I want to sort based on two fields together.

- If time1 does not exists, using time2.
- Or just use equal priority.

Either way will do. thanks

Comment: I gather you mean that considering "decending order" that you want the "largest" of the two values to be considered for sort. MongoDB cannot apply a "calculation" in a `.sort()` operation, it needs a present field. Either apply an `.aggregate()` statment to calculate or employ the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) update operator on every update to permantly keep a "maxTime" field in your document which you can then sort on.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks, I changed the question a little bit, is there way for the other?

Comment: It's really the same thing. This is not really that different in principle to this question, ["Sorting by maximum array field ascending or descending"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374433/sorting-by-maximum-array-field-ascending-or-descending/35389089#35389089), with the only real difference in that this is "two distinct fields" as opposed to an "array". But the principles to solve remain the same. You are generally **always** better off storing the field in your document with the value you want to sort on.

Comment: Agree with @Blakes Seven  and since aggregations is not supported on MiniMongo, you don't have a choice.

Comment: @MrE Depends on whether or not you can live with performing the "sort" server side and then publishing the result. But where possible, it's better to store the value and maintain it over each update.

Comment: thanks, MrE and BlakesSeven. I will go with @BlakesSeven's suggestion. store extra info in the beginning

Comment: @Blake: if you publish a cursor to the client, is it really guaranteed to be sorted the same? I think you'd want to send your subset to the client and then sort there on the subset. More efficient that way IMO.

Comment: @MrE It should be. I believe that the published "collection" internally is basically treated as an "array". So order out equals order in, unless you deliberately `.sort()` it in a different way. I've never seen published aggregate results appear in a different order to output. Anyhow, the usual point of a "server sort" is to apply `.limit()`. If you don't need that then you can just calculate and sort on display however you like.

Comment: True. Sort to first limit subset on server side. Yet I often need to search / filter more on client, and sort is usually useful there too. Anyway my point was that MiniMongo doesn't support aggregation, so Meteor does not support it OOTB. Now I just found out there are packages for it too: https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 suggestions:

1. Sort clientside - that way you can just use the arr.sort([compareFunction])
2. Transform the publications and add the field https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-transforming-collection-documents
3. Add the sortfield to the data model (update existing data), and when saving/editing objects in the future also add/edit the sortfield. Don't include the field in publications, but use it to sort when necessary.

EDIT: I would go with 3 - that way the publications would be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to handle similiar situation using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). You can try something like this:

```
OneCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      time: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $and: [
              { $ifNull: ['$time1', false] },
              { $gt: ['$time2', '$time1'] }
            ]
          },
          then: '$time1',
          else: '$time2' } }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { time: -1 } },
  { $project: { time: false } }
]);
```

It adds temporally field **time** which stores **time1** value if it exists and is greater than **time2** value or **time2** value otherwise and uses it for sorting. Then it removes **time** field from result document after sort operation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, you could try the [meteorhacks aggregate package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate), and perform the comparison in your publish method (you may want to cache the result). Note that this is untested:

```
if (Meteor.server) {
  Meteor.publish("OneCollection", function () {
    if (!this.userId) { // kick them out if they're not logged in
      this.stop();
      return;
    }
    var pipeline = [
      $project: {
        time: { $max: [ "time1", "time2" ] }
      }
    ];
    return OneCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
  }
}
```