# Positional operator and sorting

Tags: mongodb

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#sorts-and-the-positional-operator) says that:

> When the find() method includes a sort(), the find() method applies the sort() to order the matching documents before it applies the positional $ projection operator.

Arrays can't be sorted, so how would sorting the root documents affect the `$` operator?

Can anyone give a practical example?

Comment: Though you asked for a "practical example", there was the recent question ["Sorting by maximum array field, ascending or descending"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374433/sorting-by-maximum-array-field-ascending-or-descending/35389089#35389089) which rather discusses a practical solution (or solutions, depending on situation). Difference being the person asking the question already new what would happen, but was asking then how to sort on the element matching the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this means is that if your query includes a sort on the projected array field, the documents (not the arrays) will be sorted based on the full set of values in the array, not just the projected element.

Sorting documents on array fields works like this (from [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)):

> With arrays, a less-than comparison or an ascending sort compares the
>   smallest element of arrays, and a greater-than comparison or a
>   descending sort compares the largest element of the arrays.

So if you take the example data from the docs you linked to:

```javascript
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

A query like the following demonstrates the impact of the rule about projection and sorting:

```javascript
db.test.find({semester: 1, grades: {$gte: 85}}, {"grades.$": 1})
       .sort({grades: -1})
```

which outputs:

```javascript
{ 
    "_id" : 3.0, 
    "grades" : [
        85.0
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2.0, 
    "grades" : [
        90.0
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "grades" : [
        87.0
    ]
}
```

The descending sort on `grades` orders the documents based on the largest value of the full array contents, not based on just the projected value.

Comment: OK, just had to re-read that about twenty times.  The crux is, the projected value is *not* the value used for comparison.

Comment: @BanksySan Right, the sort isn't based on the projected value, the normal rules for sorting by an array field still apply.