# Aggregate with Sorting a Date not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is a very similar question on stackoverflow but for some reason this does not work. I have spent lot of time without no success.

Here is my collection setup

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5715acfcf1dbdc7c0ae94379"), 
"users":[ObjectId("570d2308ba5bc6842242e881"), 
         ObjectId("570d7e4b369ac0c525e98331")
         ],
"messages" : [
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("570d2308ba5bc6842242e881"), 
        "message" : NumberInt(0), 
        "readInd" : "N", 
        "createDate" : ISODate("2016-04-19T03:59:12.587+0000"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5715ad10f1dbdc7c0ae94396")
    }, 
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("570d2308ba5bc6842242e881"), 
        "message" : NumberInt(1), 
        "readInd" : "N", 
        "createDate" : ISODate("2016-04-19T04:11:10.541+0000"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5715afdef36f23a10ad12348")
    }, 
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("570d2308ba5bc6842242e881"), 
        "message" : NumberInt(2), 
        "readInd" : "N", 
        "createDate" : ISODate("2016-04-19T04:11:11.756+0000"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5715afdff36f23a10ad12352")
    }
]
```

}

and here is my code snipper with mongoose

```
var objId = new ObjectID("5715acfcf1dbdc7c0ae94379");

chatModel.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "users": {'$in':[objId]}} },
    {
        "$project": {
            "messages":1
        }

    }
    ,{"$sort": {"messages.createDate": -1} }
],function(err,records) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json({status: false, errCode: 900, errMsg: err});
    }

    res.json({status:true,resData:records}) ;

});
```

Thanks,

Comment: So what exactly is *"not working"*? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Sorting by maximum array field, ascending or descending"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374433/sorting-by-maximum-array-field-ascending-or-descending/)

Comment: @NeilLunn: results are getting sorted by Date

Answer (score -1):

I see two issues here.

1. Your match does not match your data structure. You should be testing against `message.user` instead of `users`:

   ```
   { "$match": { "messages.user": {'$in':[objId]}} }
   ```
2. You are testing using an ObjectId that will match the `_id` field and not the `user` field. You should be testing against `570d2308ba5bc6842242e881`, not `5715acfcf1dbdc7c0ae94379`.

If you want to test against `_id` then your match would look like this:

```
{ "$match": { "_id": {'$in':[objId]}} }
```

Comment: apologize, I updated my collection data. Please let me know if you know what is going on.